# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/title_bar.xml"

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I got strange error in developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.Main}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/title_bar.xml"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/title_bar.xml"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:129)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:366)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:357)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
at android.view.animation.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:244)
at android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation.<init>(ScaleAnimation.java:63)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:118)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:91)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:72)
at my.package.FragmentGameType.onActivityCreated(FragmentGameType.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1132)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4371)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1721)
... 11 more
```

this is the code of FragmentGameType.java:

```
110. animZoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.zoom_in);
111. animZoomOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.zoom_out);
112. animZoomInRot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.zoom_in_rot);
113. animZoomOutRot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.zoom_out_rot);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try clean your project

Comment: You should post the contents of res/drawable/title_bar.xml.

Comment: 1. This is infrequent bug, project->clean not working
2. I have no file "res/drawable/title_bar.xml" in my project.

Comment: Same issue noted on GT-P7300, android V3.1, no title_bar.xml either in my code!
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: \"res/drawable/title_bar.xml\"
 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:129)
 at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:366)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:357)
 at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
 at android.view.animation.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:244)
...

Comment: I have a similar problem on the emulator running API 12. Is having a title_bar.xml file a requirement under 3.1?

Answer (score 1):

Try to review you animations xml files,

I had similar crash when test my code in android 2.3, the problem was the animation definition of some sentence, look lines, such as:

android:fromXScale="1%"

android:toXScale="100%"

fromXScale,toXScale needs a float parameter, don’t like "100%",  for that, in API       level 10 I received java.lang.NumberFormatException.
It is no supported for  API 10, however in  higher  It  work well, that creates confusion.

I changed the code for:

android:fromXScale="0.1"

android:toXScale="1.0

And problem solved.

Comment: Just a question: If 1.0 equals 100%, wouldn't 1% be the equivalent for 0.01?

Comment: In addition to that, should I use only a common number - "10", for instance - if I wanted to refer to 10dp? Because I have a scale animation that goes from 100% to 4dp, and it gets messy if I set it from "1.0" to "4".

Comment: Yes it is,  0.01 is the 1%.  For other hand. It  is not messy  if  you know the  100%  in dp  then you can do the same relation.

Comment: Too bad it would be always relative to screen size.

Comment: it is relative to image size. Doest not about any screeen.  The original code is about  of one animation. then android:fromXScale="0.1"  and android:toXScale="1.0  is relative to image size.